# How can I know the value of some parameter (say w) during a parallel calculation in Mathematica?

Tags: evaluation

I am computing something like `ParallelTable[{w, f[w]},{w,0,10,1/100}]`, in which `f[w]` is a numerically obtained function that demands much time to do so. During the time in which the code is running, how can I know the current value of `w`?

Obs.: If the code was `Table[{w, f[w]},{w,0,10,1/100}]` (without parallelization), I could just create a new cell with `w` and evaluate it in subsession (by pressing *F7* instead of *Shift + Enter*).

Comment: You could `Monitor[...]` the `w` in the `Table` case e.g `Monitor[Table[Pause[1]; w^2, {w, 1, 100}], w]`, but in a `ParallelTable` you'll have multiple `w` going on at once so you will need multiple `Monitor`s. This is kind of awkward and brings down performance.

Comment: ^ and the problem with Monitor in parallel kernels is that those kernels don't have a front end. You should try [`ResourceFunction["ParallelMapMonitored"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ParallelMapMonitored)

Comment: Or similar to @flinty's suggestion, there is also the more general [`ResourceFunction["MonitorProgress"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MonitorProgress/), e.g. `ResourceFunction["MonitorProgress"][ParallelTable[{w, f[w]}, {w,0,10,1/100}]] `